# Need example of binding LIKE DB2 statements in PHP

Tags: php, db2, prepared-statement

I am trying to do something similar to this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = ? AND order LIKE ?%"
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

db2_bind_param($stmt, 1, "userName", DB2_PARAM_IN);
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "orderNum", DB2_PARAM_IN);

db2_execute($stmt);
```

Of course, its not the right way to do LIKE ?%. I'm just looking for the correct way to bind a parameter like that but also use the % wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick the parameter with the wildcard characters in the string.  You'll want to do something like ([see example #12)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = ? AND order LIKE ?"
```

and

```
$orderNum = '%' . $your_order_num . '%';
db2_bind_param($stmt, 2, "orderNum", DB2_PARAM_IN);
```

Comment: Gives me two errors when I try it like that, "Value Not Bound" and "Bind Error 3" on the line that has db2_execute($stmt)

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize the third parameter was actually the variable name that you're binding the value from (I've never really used DB2 with PHP).  I've updated the answer to something I think should work.  Basically, the wildcard should be inside whatever is being bound to the parameter.  The database engine should stick the bound value wholesale into the query at the parameter marker.